# How do I compile a .java file without having package data?

Tags: java, class, compilation, package

I'm trying to compile a .java file into a .class file so I can use it as a 3rd party class that I load during runtime from a different package/program. I've run into the problem however of having package data and I get a NoClassDefFoundError. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: What means *without having package data*?

Comment: Also, how do you load it in the other package?

Answer (score 0):

So from what I read I got that you want to separately compile a class of yours and and another program and then be able to merge them in some way during runtime. As far as I know that is not possible. You will have to compile this specific .java file alongside the program you are talking about. You will have to make use of the import statement as well in the .java files of the program that are going to use your class.

Comment: A ClassNotFoundError occurs at runtime, not at compile time.

Comment: Well I did not actually specify what kind of error occurs. I just mentioned that it wont work. :)